# new addition and new multiplication x ⊕ y = x + y − 1, x ⊗ y = x + y − xy on set Z, prove the set Z equipped with these 2 new operation

Tags: ring-theory, multiplicative-function

here says a new operation addition and new operation multiplication  x ⊕ y = x + y − 1, x ⊗ y = x + y − xy on set Z,where the operations on the right hand side are ordinary addition and multiplication of integers. Prove that the set Z equipped with these two
new operations ⊕, ⊗ is a ring. Does it have a multiplicative identity?

I tried to use the addition cancellation but I do not understand why or I got the wrong understanding for this question.

I assume the there is y and y' are 2 solution for equation  x ⊕ y = x + y − 1, therefore:
  x ⊕ y = x + y − 1
 x ⊕ y' = x + y − 1
and I get  x ⊕ y =  x ⊕ y' after the cancellation, then I get y=y', and it means the addictive is unique. So, can I say that the set Z equipped with new addiction x ⊕ y = x + y − 1? or I just go into a wrong way for solve this problem?

ask in advance, thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ Any set bijection $\,h:R'\to R\,$ serves to [transport the ring structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure) of $\,(R,+,*,0,1),$ to $\,(R',\oplus,\otimes,0',1') \,$ by defining the operations in $\,R'\,$ to make $\,h\,$ be a ring isomorphism, i.e.

$$\ \ \  \begin{align} &x \oplus y\, =\ h^{-1}(h(x) + h(y)),\quad 0' = h^{-1}(0)\\  
 &x \otimes y\, =\, h^{-1}(h(x)\, *\, h(y)),\quad 1' = h^{-1}(1)\end{align}$$
$\begin{align}\Longrightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  h(x\oplus y)\ =\ h(x) + h(y), & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ h(x\otimes y)\ =\ \ \ h(x) * h(y)\\[.3em]
{\rm e.g.}\ \ h(x)=1\!-\!x\!:\ \  1\! -\! (x\!+\!y\!-\!1) =\, 1\!-\!x + 1\!-\!y, & \ \ \ \ 1\!-\!(x\!+\!y\!-\!xy) = (1\!-\!x)*(1\!-\!y)\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

You will need to prove that all the ring axioms are true if, throughout the axioms, $+$ is replaced by $\oplus$ and $\times$ is replaced by $\otimes$.  It may also be necessary to give a new meaning to $0$, $-x$ and $1$.  Indeed, it may not be possible to give any meaning to $1$: this is what is meant by the question "does it have a multiplicative identity?".

Here is one example: the associative law for addition says
$$x\oplus(y\oplus z)=(x\oplus y)\oplus z$$
for all $x,y,z$.  To prove this is true, we have
$$\eqalign{LHS
  &=x\oplus(y+z-1)\cr
  &=x+(y+z-1)-1\cr
  &=x+y+z-2\cr
  RHS
  &=(x+y-1)\oplus z\cr
  &=(x+y-1)+z-1\cr
  &=x+y+z-2\cr
  &=LHS\ .\cr}$$
See if you can do the other axioms for yourself.

Comment: firstly, thank you, and did you replace the x⊕y by x+y-1 and z replace by z-1 in your example?

Comment: In any expression you replace$$\langle\hbox{something}\rangle\oplus\langle\hbox{something else}\rangle$$by$$\langle\hbox{something}\rangle+\langle\hbox{something else}\rangle-1\ .$$This is what the given definition means.